# I cannot launch Anaconda after I had to hard shut-down my PC. I use anaconda-navigator in terminal to launch

Tags: anaconda

```
jeeth@jeeth-Scrybe-code:~$ anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeeth/Software/Anaconda/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/jeeth/Software/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 125, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.logs import clean_logs
  File "/home/jeeth/Software/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/logs.py", line 18, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config import (LOG_FILENAME, LOG_FOLDER,
  File "/home/jeeth/Software/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.config.main import CONF
  File "/home/jeeth/Software/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/main.py", line 67, in <module>
    raw_mode=True,
  File "/home/jeeth/Software/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.load_from_ini()
  File "/home/jeeth/Software/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config/user.py", line 279, in load_from_ini
    self.read(self.filename(), encoding='utf-8')
  File "/home/jeeth/Software/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 697, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/home/jeeth/Software/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1015, in _read
    for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
  File "/home/jeeth/Software/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaf in position 5: invalid start byte
```

Comment: This looks like it might be what you need, try the recommendations here and let us know if they don’t work: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/7256

Comment: This is what worked: conda install anaconda-clean, anaconda-clean --yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked

```
conda install anaconda-clean

anaconda-clean --yes
```

Thanks to everyone on Stack Exchange. Couldn't have fixed this without your help.